# Loading data from Multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have a schema hierarchy like this:

```
Organization > Program >RegistryPatientCount
```

so RegistryPatientCount keeps `program_id` field to access `Program` table. ( let's say it also has a **Name** column, for like program name, etc..)

`Program` table keeps `organization_id` field to access `Organization` table.

Then in my `controller#show` method I have something like this:

```
 respond_to :json

  def show
    #TODO: Pagination.
    @blah =  Program.includes([:registry_patient_counts]).where(organization_id: params[:id])

    respond_with(@blah)
  end
```

*NOTE: the ID param is organization_id .*

When I run this, it is returning the data from the `Program` table, but I wanted it to return 
data from `RegistryPatientCount` table, and next step would be to be able to drill into Program table and instead of program_id would be able to show Name from Program table.

But nothing is working, like I said it just returning data of Program table for the given organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the `respond_with` that it should include the child elements.

```
respond_with(@blah, include: :registry_patient_counts)
```

---

The `Program.includes(...)` just tells ActiveRecord to fetch all data with one query. Then you can work with it inside the controller without doing extra database queries.

But the `respond with` and `render` methods are independent from that. They usually only return the first level of the hierarchy.

Comment: but I do have includes and registry_patient_counts in the first call and assigning it to @blah ... why should i redo it in respond_with?

Comment: I've told you already in my answer ... Read it again: `Program.includes(...)` = ActiveRecord and `respond_with(..., include: )` = JSON rendering. Those are two different things. The first one is to optimize the database query (look up 'eager loading': http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) and the second one ist about how the resulting JSON will look (= what data it will include).

Comment: Ok makes sense...so probably the better way is to use JBUILDER and parse and massage that @blah that is coming back and use that one.

Comment: I don't know JBUILDER, seems to be like `rabl`: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl , http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl . But then I found this: https://twitter.com/steveklabnik/status/246920008658190337 , he says you should use this: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers . So 3 different gems. It's your choice :)

Answer (score -1):

In irb or Rails console(rails c), can you see if you get data from "RegistryPatientCount".
Then if that works plug the code into the controller or where you doing this.
Assuming you have model in place and field called "organization_id" I would try this:

@blah =  RegistryPatientCount.where(:organization_id => params[:id])

Comment: nop, RegistryPatientCount doesn't have organization_id field.  Please read the question again, I explained the schema